# MySQL import - CSV - file refuses to be properly imported

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I'm trying to import the following file into a MySQL Db:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1WbRdNgqVre3wN4DpJZ-08jtGkJtCDJNQ?usp=sharing

Using the "data import wizard" on MySql Workbench, for some reason I'm getting "218\223 lines imported successfully", whereas the file contains close to 100K.
I tried looking for special chars around lines 210-230, also removing all of them, but still the same happens.

The file is a CSV of Microsoft Bing's geo locations, used in Microsoft Advertising campaigns, downloaded from Microsoft's website (using an ad account there).
I've been googling, reading, StackOverflowing, playing with the file and different import options...

I tried cutting the file into small bits, and the newly created file was completely corrupt somehow...
Encoding seems to be UTF-8, line breaks all "\n". I tried changing them all into "\r\n" using notepad++, but still the same happens.

File opens normally in Excel, looks normal, passes CSVlint.io...

The only weird thing is that the file contains quotes on some of the values but not on the rest (e.g. line 219. Yeah I know it sounds like this would be the problem, but I removed it, and all the rest of the lines with quotes, and it still happens... Also tried loading with ENCLOSED BY ", see below).

I also tried using SQL statements to import:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:\\Users\\Gilad\\Downloads\\GeoLocations.csv'
INTO TABLE aw_geo_map_bmsl
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
(tried also with: ENCLOSED BY '"')
LINES TERMINATED BY '/n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

(had to add `OPT_LOCAL_INFILE=1` to the connection on `Advanced` for MySQL Workbench to be allowed access to local files on my computer)

This gives `0 rows affected`.

Help?

Comment: I see complete CREATE TABLE script for destination table nowhere...

Comment: PS. The problematic row is ```232,Saint Pierre and Miquelon,Country,,Deprecated,``` which causes an error due to incorrect integer value. Use input preprocessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Epilogue: In the end I just gave up on all these import wizards and did it the old "make your SQL statements from Excel" way.

I imported the CSV data into Excel. Watch out: in this case I found I needed to use a data import wizard from Excel (but that one worked perfectly) to be able to change the encoding to UTF, which Excel 2010 chose as "windows" which was wrong.

After processing the data a bit to my liking, I used the following *Excel* code:

```
=CONCATENATE("INSERT INTO aw_geo_map_bmsl (`Location Id`,Name,`Canonical Name`,`Location Type`,Status,`Adwords Location Id`)
 VALUES (",
A2,
",""",B2,"""",
",""",C2,"""",
",""",D2,"""",
",""",E2,"""",
",",F2,");")
```

to generate INSERT statements for every line, then copy-pasted and pasted only values, then pasted into an editor, removed additional quotes that Excel adds, and ran it in MySQL Workbench, which runs it line by line (takes some time), and you can see the progress.

Saved me hours of unsuccessfully playing around with "automatic tools" which fail for unknown reasons and don't give proper logs ootb.

Warning: do NOT do this for unsanitized code as it's vulnerable to SQL injection. In this case it was data from Microsoft so I know it's fine.